Why Bhagavad Gita mentioned karna at first day of war of kurukshetra
According to  shreemad Bhagavad Gita Duryodhana count karna in his army saina Nayak or leader list like asvatama and kripacharya in first day of war of Kurukshetra in verse 1.7,1.8 and other verses of Mahabharata said that he was joined battlefield at 11 th day of war of kurukshetra so how this is possible if karna was not present at first day of kurukshetra war so why duryodhana duryodhana count karna in his army saina Nayak or leader like kripacharya and asvatama?

Karna was in Kuru Kshetra. he was just in tent waiting for his turn. in cricket, you count all batsmen even though just openers go to play and other batsmen’s turn come very late..

But in chapter 11 verse 26 said all dhritrashtra sons and his allies like karna and pandav army persons also going into the mouth visavroop of krishna so if karna was in camp so how it was possible that Arjun seeing karna also going into the mouth of the lord krishna visavroop?

That was future scene anyway.

This question is similar to: Why did the Bhagavad Gita mention Karna at first day of war of Kurukshetra?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
