Why did the Bhagavad Gita mention Karna at first day of war of Kurukshetra?
Why did the Bhagavad Gita verse 1.7, 1.8 and 11.26, 11.32,11.33, and11.34 say that Karna joined the battlefield alongside the Kurava army on first day of war while other verses of Mahabharata said that he joined the battlefield at 11 th day? Why both verses of bhagvad gita contradictory to each other?

You have asked 2 same Qs, another being https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/60046/16823

Karna was still on the Battlefield even when he was not fighting. Krishna met Karna on the battlefield just before the war began -

"Vasudeva then went to Radha’s son on the field of battle. And the
elder brother of Gada, for the sake of the Pandavas, then said to
Karna,—It has been heard by me, O Karna, that from hatred of Bhishma
you will not fight. Come to our side, O son of Radha, and (stay with
us) as long as Bhishma is not slain. After Bhishma is slain, O son of
Radha, you mayst then again engage in battle on Duryodhana’s side, if
you have no preference for any of the parties."


Section XLIII, Bhagavad Gita parva, Mahabharata.


Sir thank you so much for hard work but can you please give me the verse in sanskrit
